# How to have table completely ignore browser width?

Tags: html, css

I have a table whose cell width adjusts depending on the browser's viewport width.

I'm trying to make it so that the table does not respond at all to viewport width, and that the width of each cell is just as wide as it needs to be without linebreaking.

I've tried setting

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

and

```
table { position: absolute }
```

and

```
table { min-width: 100% }
```

but none of these seem to work. Also I'd like to just use CSS and not JS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
td {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

This should prevent the content in the cells to break, forcing the cells to be as wide as necessary to display the content.